# Scheduler Processing using Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

we have a requirement to process millions of records using spring batch . We have planned  to use a Spring Batch to do this by reading the db using **JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder** and process in chunks and write it to Kaafka Queue. The active consumers of the queue will process the chunks of data and update the db

The consumer task is to iterate every item from the chunk and invoke the external api's.
In case the external system is down or not responding with success response , there should be retries of atleast 3 times and considering that each task in the chunk has to do this, what would be the ideal approach?

Another use case to consider, what happens when the job is processing and the system goes down and say that the job has already processed 10000 record and the remaining records are yet to be processed . After the restart how to make sure the execution doesnt restart the entire process from beginning and to resume from the point of failure.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch creates the following tables. You can use them to check the status of your job and customize your scheduler to behave in a way you see fit.

I'd use the step execution Id in BATCH_STEP_EXCECUTION to validate the status that's set and then retry based off on that status, Or something similar to that sense.

```
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS
BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE
BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION
```

Comment: yes it is getting created. Let me check on how to evaluate to start the job from the point of failure instead of the entire process from start.